# QTWebkit 4.6 and ico images, Rendering problem

Tags: qt, webkit, qtwebkit

I have a local html file which I'm trying to view using QTWebKit, there are some images in the file which are of type ".ico" which seems that QTWebKit is not able to render them as it gives a question mark icon instead.

I tried opening the html file in firefox and its working fine and all images gets rendered.

My question is, does QTWebKit support ico images, and if it does... what should I do to enable webkit to render ico images?

Regards

Comment: just guessing... but I would presume that webkit does not support ICO images within HTML content as they are not a valid Web Image format. [GIF,JPEG,PNG] only.

Comment: hmmm, well this takes me to the other part of my question I guess... how can I enable QTwebkit to render ico images.

I have tried my page on chrome and it was rendered perfectly, which makes me guess that it could be done also in qtwebkit since chrome is based on webkit.

I'm not asking for the code that does it or anything, just something that gets me on the right track would be nice.

Comment: The platform ImageDecoder constructor in src/3rdparty/webkit/WebCore/platform/image-decoders/ImageDecoder.cpp contains a test for .ico formats and creates an ICOImageDecoder if the test succeeds. Perhaps your images fail the test? You could start by looking at that file.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your Qt is built without ICO support? In Qt ICO is usually an image plugin. Check if it exists in your Qt installation ($prefix/plugins/imageformats/)

Comment: Nope both debug and release versions of qico4 (DLL and lib) are there.